# Mac mini (G4 PowerPC) won't boot. How can I reset it to factory defaults?

Tags: boot, mac

I have the first version of the Mac mini I have not used it for many years. Mac Mini wichi is a 1.25GHz PowerPC G4 model from 2005

The last time I tried to use it, I was trying to get some flavor of Linux running on the Mac mini (not sure what version exactly).

I was pretty sure that the Mini had a CD inside, and was I trying to eject it and get the Mac OS X running again.

I have managed to get into the boot menu, but it shows me only this:

[image: bootmenu]

To me seems to be showing that it does NOT have a CD to eject right? I have tried using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or holding <kbd>F12</kbd> or also holding left mouse during boot without any success

When I let the boot proccess continue it shows me this, but then the image starts to flash (like when trying to configure graphical environment) and then just stays black

[image: fail]

What can I do to recover the original macOS and configurations?

I have tried to used <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while booting but did nothing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on a Windows keyboard)

https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/factory-reset-mac-mini-m1.html#Before_Factory_Reset_Macmini

**UPDATE**: Based on the comments on this question I have pressed, a Windows keyboard, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, I was able to get hear the two boot chimes, and after a while I got the "out of sync" image of the Apple logo with the loading circle for two seconds and then is all black

I just bought a DVI to HDMI converter that I'm unable to test somewhere else, could that be the cause ?

**The rest of the discussion is happening here**

https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/reviving-a-mac-mini-powerpc-not-booting-correctly-video-is-out-of-sync-bli

Comment: Did you try holding Cmd-S at boot for Single User Mode? Sometimes a partially damaged install of Mac OS X can still boot into Single User Mode even when it can't boot all the way into the GUI. You could also try holding Cmd-Opt-P-R at boot until you hear the boot chime a second time, to reset the PRAM, in case some errant boot-time setting stored in PRAM is causing the boot failure.

Comment: The boot chime is not even playing, but I will try this

Comment: @Spiff I have UPDATED the question with what happens after the second boot  chime

Comment: It sounds like resetting the PRAM didn't help, but it cleared your boot-args so you're no longer set to boot verbosely. If you want to boot verbosely again to confirm that boot is halting at the same place, boot while holding down Cmd-V. If you want to boot verbosely every time, you could boot into Open Firmware by holding down Cmd-Opt-O-F at boot, and then doing something like `setenv boot-args -v`; `saveenv`; `reset-all` (but double-check me on that, it's been a long time since I've messed with OF. Check out http://mac-classic.com/articles/open-firmware-basics/ .

Comment: Also, since rehabbing an 18-year-old PowerPC Mac is firmly in retrocomputing territory, you might want to ask in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ . At this point, if I were you, and I really really wanted to see what's on the disk, I'd hold T at boot to boot into FireWire Target Disk Mode, and connect it via FireWire to another Mac (possibly via a Firewire to Thunderbolt dongle if necessary), to see if the "good" Mac can see or mount any partitions of the Mac mini's drive. Otherwise I'd burn an old version of Mac OS X boot/install DVD-ROM, boot from it and just do an erase-install.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, before posting there, any ideas on why a MacOS ISO imaged burned into a USB (from Windows 10) is not detected in the boot menu ?

Comment: Here is the follow up question https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26612/reviving-a-mac-mini-powerpc-not-booting-correctly-video-is-out-of-sync-bli

Comment: PowerPC Macs required boot drives to use the old Apple Partition Map (APM) format, not MBR or GPT. If your disk image didn't start with an APM, that's why it wasn't recognized.

Comment: well, if you want to know what flavor of linux, must have been yellow dog linux, as this is about the only distro for this hardware

Comment: @camelccc yellow dog linux is discontinued as my hardware ;-) any specific version ?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a G4 system with PowerPC CPU and OS X 10.6 or earlier, the only way to recover it is by booting from the installer DVD. I found multiple articles / vids on how to start the recovery with a bit different sets of instructions but nothing I copy-paste, and as I've never installed a Mac this old can't write one.

If the install disk is lost, MacOS Tiger Retail DVD ISO can be downloaded from [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/macosx10.4tigerretaildvd)

---

How to restore OSX on an Intel-based Mac, from [Apple Knowledgebase](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac):

1. When starting the system immediately press and hold one of these key combinations, depending on what you want to do:

   a. Install the latest version of macOS compatible with your computer: Option-Command-R.

   b. Reinstall your computer’s original version of macOS (including available updates): Option-Shift-Command-R.

   c. Reinstall your current version of macOS: Command-R.
2. In the Recovery app window, select Reinstall for your macOS release, then click Continue.
3. Follow the onscreen instructions.
4. In the settings where you select a volume, select your current macOS volume (in most cases, it’s the only one available).

---

Comment: [I deleted my previous comment to revise.] I see he says he has the original Mac mini, which would be the 1.25GHz PowerPC G4 model from 2005. Most of these instructions probably don't apply.

Comment: The only thing I know is what they told, a first gen Mac Mini, which are among the first Intel-based Macs produced. I don't know whether those supported internet recovery. Sure, if the OP does add the Mac model, I can try to search the appropriate instructions from Apple KB. Or maybe they're searching for it just now :-)

Comment: Uh - did they actually produce PPC Mac Minis??? I did search before posting, and according to what I found they were introduced at the Intel switch time.

Comment: Bloody heck, they did, at least so Wikipedia says. Well, the instruction does say "On an Intel-based Mac" so...

Comment: I apologize for my less-than-helpful initial comments. I clearly started commenting before I'd read his post carefully enough.

Comment: LOL mate them was very helpful :-D But accepted nonetheless :-) I'm gonna update my answer in a few.

Comment: 1. How can anyone go to the apple menu when the mac can not boot regardelss of the model ? 2. This first Mac Mini wichi is a 1.25GHz PowerPC G4 model from 2005